# Javascript Functions as constants

Tags: javascript, constants

I have inheritted some code and I've very rarely used JS.  In the code, athere are losts of functions which are defined into contstants.  I'm trying to debug an issue using a browser, and I am struggling to call any of the functions from the commandline

can anyone let me know how I would do this please.  Example below (not actual code)

```
const updateDisplay = function () {
    if (0x0 === seq[hl_0b('0x8', '3D61')]) {
        return;
    }
    if (0x1 === seq[hl_0b('0x16', 'Sg%G')]) {
        get('display')['innerText'] = '';
    }
    const a = 0x32 * (seq[hl_0b('0x7', '7U46')] - 0x1 - get(hl_0b('0x22', 'uOD4'))[hl_0b('0x24', 'Mu]C')]['length']);
    setTimeout(function (b) {
        get(hl_0b('0x2b', 'Q0y5'))[hl_0b('0x10', 'Zu59')] += seq[b];
        buttonFlash(null, hl_0b('0x5', 'lRst') + seq[b]);
    }, a, seq[hl_0b('0x1e', '2f%K')] - 0x1);
};
```

Updated to include actual code

Comment: To just call the function, it is the function name (updateDisplay) followed by (). So updateDisplay() should work.

Comment: you can use `debugger;` for example. Anyway - this is too abstract, please create a [mcve]

Comment: updateDisplay() returns undefined?

Answer (score 0):

to create a constant function you need to call it with const instead of constant. After that you can create your function as

```
const toto = function(){
    /*DO SOMETHING*/
}
```

This function can be write as an arrow function to as

```
const toto = () => {/*DO SOMETHING*/}
```

Anyway, this is links for documentations if you want

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Function

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_const.asp

Comment: I aready have the functions defined, I just can't get any of them to fire from my browser command line in debug